# How to encode core data to JSON with no slash in Swift or Php

Tags: php, json, swift

My php will return error if the JSON have "/n" and "/". I'm not sure I need to change my php code or my swift code.

my php code

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($obj);
```

it look like fail to decode?

```
Array ( [0] => {"user":"1","accbooktype":"æµæ°´è´¦æœ¬","accbookname":"æ—¥å¸¸","accbookid":"1","category":"æ—¥å¸¸","cid":"U1L2B555"} )
```

[image]

Success output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cid] => 5 [accbookname] => test [accbooktype] => test [category] => test [user] => test ) )
```

[image]

This is my swift code. If change the code here. I need to know how to encode the core data to JSON with no slash, how?

```
//newdict is Core data
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newdict, options: [.prettyPrinted])

//I tried this also but not worked
//let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
//let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(newdict)

let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
bookJSON.append(jsonString!)

print(bookJSON)
```

output:

```
["{\n  \"cid\" : \"U1L2B1\",\n  \"user\" : \"1\",\n  \"accbooktype\" : \"流水账本\",\n  \"accbookname\" : \"日常\",\n  \"accbookid\" : \"1\",\n  \"category\" : \"日常\"\n}"]
```

To this

```
[
    {
        "cid": "5",
        "accbookname" : "test",
        "accbooktype": "test",
        "category": "test",
        "user": "test"
    }
]
```

Comment: You allready get two times encoded json from file_get_contents('php://input');
remove json encoding in other side, where you make call to endpoint and pass data. Also you might need to encode to utf8 your data before passing to endpoint because of special characters.

Comment: I don't need to encode the dictionary to JSON in swift? @Eimsas

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($request);
```

**you can also use type casting**

```
$request = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```